# Using multiple controllers cause session error codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

When I use only 1 controller in my application, user, everything works fine. When I try to use 2 or 3 to divide the code and create some structure my application always give the following error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/application/controllers/Project.php:99)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 140

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/application/controllers/Project.php
Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Googled it and tried many things but can't find an answer. I'm using codeigniter 3. My User controller looks like :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * User class.
 * 
 * @extends CI_Controller
 */
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
        $this->load->model('project_model');
    }

public function createProject() {
        if ($_SESSION['userlevel']) {
            if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] < 3) {
                $userid = $this->uri->segment(3);
            } else {
                $userid = $this->input->post('userproject');
            }
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_name', 'project name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|callback_is_project_name_unique[' . $this->input->post('project_name') . ']');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_address', 'project address', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_description', 'project description', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_city', 'project city', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
                $this->load->view('header', $data);
                if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] < 3) {
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project', $data);
                } else {
                    $data['userslist'] = $this->user_model->get_users_list();
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project_admin', $data);
                }
                $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
            } else {

                $Address = urlencode($this->input->post('project_address'));
                $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" . $Address . "&sensor=true";
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
                $status = $xml->status;
                if ($status == "OK") {
                    $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
                    $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
                    $LatLng = "$Lat,$Lon";
                }

//pass validation
                $data = array(
                    'project_name' => $this->input->post('project_name'),
                    'project_address' => $this->input->post('project_address'),
                    'project_description' => $this->input->post('project_description'),
                    'project_city' => $this->input->post('project_city'),
                    'project_finished' => $this->input->post('project_finished'),
                    'lat' => $Lat,
                    'lng' => $Lon,
                );

//$this->db->insert('tbl_user', $data);
                if ($this->user_model->create_project($data, $userid, $this->input->post('project_name'))) {

                    if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] > 1) {
                        $data['projectlist'] = $this->user_model->get_project_list();
                        $data['uncompleted_projects'] = $this->user_model->get_uncompleted_projects();
                        $data['completed_projects'] = $this->user_model->get_completed_projects();
                    } else {
                        $data['projectlist'] = $this->user_model->get_project_list_userid($userid);
                    }
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_projects', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                } else {
                    $data->error = 'There was a problem creating your new employee. Please try again.';
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    // send error to the view
                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My second controller, the project controller. This is the controller I want to use know to paste the createproject code so this gives more structure. But when I paste it here and adapt my views it gives the error. here's my project_controller code:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
 * File Name: employee.php
 */

class Project extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
        $this->load->model('customer_model');

    }

    public function createProject() {
//same as usercontroller
```

My User/login code in User controller :

```
public function login() {
        $loggedin = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if (!$loggedin) {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_mail', 'user mail', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'user password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                $data = new stdClass();
                $data->error = 'Check your user and password';
                $this->load->view('dashboard_login', $data);
            } else {
                $usermail = $this->input->post('user_mail');
                $password = $this->input->post('user_password');

                if ($this->user_model->resolve_user_login($usermail, $password)) {

                    $user_id = $this->user_model->get_user_id_from_mail($usermail);
                    $user = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);

                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = (string) $user->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = (bool) true;
                    $_SESSION['user_gsm'] = (string) $user->user_gsm;
                    $_SESSION['user_address'] = (string) $user->user_address;
                    $_SESSION['user_city'] = (string) $user->user_city;
                    $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $this->user_model->get_user_level((int) $user->user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $usermail;
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] == "3") {
                        $data['employeetotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_employees();
                        $data['customertotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_customers();
                        $data['projectstotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_projects();
                    }
                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_index', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                } else {
                    $data = new stdClass();
                    // login failed
                    $data->error = 'Wrong username or password.';
                    // send error to the view
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_login', $data);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
            $data['employeetotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_employees();
            $data['customertotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_customers();
            $data['projectstotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_projects();
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard_index', $data);
            $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
        }
    }
```

In config/autoload I've got following:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Answer (score 0):

The session library should be automatically loaded for you. There's no reason for you to include it in each of your constructor functions.

Remove it from both controllers, and it'll work fine.

If it does not work, check in your `config/autoload.php` file to make sure it is being loaded there correctly.

Comment: I removed it in my both controllers and in my autoload.php I have :$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');

So, I think that is ok? But I still get the error..

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem , notice that the error is on `line 99` on your controller `Project.php` (you should have only 76 lines if I am correct). I bet your controller doesn't have 99 lines ... delete the extra lines and the error will vanish. 
or if you have an echo on `line 99` comment it

hope that helps!