# Using multiple controllers in Codeigniter : cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

When I use only 1 controller in my application, user, everything works fine. When I try to use 2 or 3 to divide the code and create some structure my application always give the following error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/application/controllers/Project.php:99)

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 140

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/application/controllers/Project.php
Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BT_dashboard/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Googled it and tried many things but can't find an answer. I'm using codeigniter 3. My User controller looks like :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * User class.
 * 
 * @extends CI_Controller
 */
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
        $this->load->model('project_model');
    }

public function createProject() {
        if ($_SESSION['userlevel']) {
            if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] < 3) {
                $userid = $this->uri->segment(3);
            } else {
                $userid = $this->input->post('userproject');
            }
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_name', 'project name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|callback_is_project_name_unique[' . $this->input->post('project_name') . ']');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_address', 'project address', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_description', 'project description', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('project_city', 'project city', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
                $this->load->view('header', $data);
                if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] < 3) {
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project', $data);
                } else {
                    $data['userslist'] = $this->user_model->get_users_list();
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project_admin', $data);
                }
                $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
            } else {

                $Address = urlencode($this->input->post('project_address'));
                $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" . $Address . "&sensor=true";
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
                $status = $xml->status;
                if ($status == "OK") {
                    $Lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
                    $Lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
                    $LatLng = "$Lat,$Lon";
                }

//pass validation
                $data = array(
                    'project_name' => $this->input->post('project_name'),
                    'project_address' => $this->input->post('project_address'),
                    'project_description' => $this->input->post('project_description'),
                    'project_city' => $this->input->post('project_city'),
                    'project_finished' => $this->input->post('project_finished'),
                    'lat' => $Lat,
                    'lng' => $Lon,
                );

//$this->db->insert('tbl_user', $data);
                if ($this->user_model->create_project($data, $userid, $this->input->post('project_name'))) {

                    if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] > 1) {
                        $data['projectlist'] = $this->user_model->get_project_list();
                        $data['uncompleted_projects'] = $this->user_model->get_uncompleted_projects();
                        $data['completed_projects'] = $this->user_model->get_completed_projects();
                    } else {
                        $data['projectlist'] = $this->user_model->get_project_list_userid($userid);
                    }
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_projects', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                } else {
                    $data->error = 'There was a problem creating your new employee. Please try again.';
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    // send error to the view
                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_add_project', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My second controller, the project controller. This is the controller I want to use know to paste the createproject code so this gives more structure. But when I paste it here and adapt my views it gives the error. here's my project_controller code:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
 * File Name: employee.php
 */

class Project extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
        $this->load->model('customer_model');

    }

    public function createProject() {
//same as usercontroller
```

My User/login code in User controller :

```
public function login() {
        $loggedin = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if (!$loggedin) {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_mail', 'user mail', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'user password', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                $data = new stdClass();
                $data->error = 'Check your user and password';
                $this->load->view('dashboard_login', $data);
            } else {
                $usermail = $this->input->post('user_mail');
                $password = $this->input->post('user_password');

                if ($this->user_model->resolve_user_login($usermail, $password)) {

                    $user_id = $this->user_model->get_user_id_from_mail($usermail);
                    $user = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);

                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = (string) $user->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = (bool) true;
                    $_SESSION['user_gsm'] = (string) $user->user_gsm;
                    $_SESSION['user_address'] = (string) $user->user_address;
                    $_SESSION['user_city'] = (string) $user->user_city;
                    $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $this->user_model->get_user_level((int) $user->user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $usermail;
                    $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;

                    if ($_SESSION['userlevel'] == "3") {
                        $data['employeetotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_employees();
                        $data['customertotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_customers();
                        $data['projectstotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_projects();
                    }
                    $this->load->view('header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_index', $data);
                    $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
                } else {
                    $data = new stdClass();
                    // login failed
                    $data->error = 'Wrong username or password.';
                    // send error to the view
                    $this->load->view('dashboard_login', $data);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $data['userdata'] = $this->session->userdata;
            $data['employeetotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_employees();
            $data['customertotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_customers();
            $data['projectstotal'] = $this->user_model->get_amount_projects();
            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard_index', $data);
            $this->load->view('wrapper', $data);
        }
    }
```

In config/autoload I've got following:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Comment: Have you write any where `start _session();` in your code? You should use codeignitor session library instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: You mean like this? $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

Comment: Yes. Codeignitor not using PHP Native session. Have look [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: do not use `start_session()` instead set session data when you allow user to log in, DO NOT USE $_SESSION with Codeigniter.

Comment: No that is incorrect, both the superglobal and the magic getter or userdata() method are perfectly fine for usage in CI. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple controllers cause session error codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446514/using-multiple-controllers-cause-session-error-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

So, what is on line 99 in your Project.php controller?

Comment: problem solved I needed to delete the ?> at the end of the controller